# How are WPF and Silverlight different?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between WPF and Silverlight, what features have been added and removed from WPF in order to get Silverlight?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666058/wpf-vs-silverlight-3-0

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633379/what-net-wpf-features-do-you-miss-when-working-in-silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Silverlight is an implementation of the CLI just like MS.NET and Mono. That is SL owns a BCL and a Garbage Collector among other features while WPF is a library framework. SL provides a subset (an useful one) of the presentation capabilites that WPF offers and add a few things new like VisualStateManager.

you should check the online documentation, there is the complete list.